# Opening other exe like notepad.exe work but not regedit.exe in C

Tags: c, registry, exe, regedit

I came across some code that started a exe specified by the path. However, it doesn't work for regedit.exe. Program doesn't do anything. Not even pop up the UAC pop up when you double click on the exe icon normally. Why is that? Is there a way to get it to work?

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <processthreadsapi.h>

    int main()
    {
        STARTUPINFOW siStartupInfo; 
        PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo; 

        memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo)); 
        memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo)); 

        siStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartupInfo); 

        if (CreateProcessW(L"C:\\Windows\\regedit.exe", 
                            NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
                            0, NULL, NULL, 
                            &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo)) 

        return 0;
    }
```

The same code works if you sub `regedit.exe` with `notepad.exe`. No errors or anything on compile. Running code just does nothing.

Comment: Could it be something related to administrator rights?

Comment: maybe try `if (CreateProcessW(...)) return 0; else perror("create process");`

Comment: Does launching `C:\windows\regedit.exe` work as you expect from the command line?

Comment: @SteveFriedl yeah it works fine from the command line

Comment: ... then the suggestion from @pmg is on point: see if it's actually working, or the error if not.

Comment: @pmg `perror("create process")` comes back as "No error"

Comment: I'm not actually sure that `perror()` is the right thing here for a Win32 error (as opposed to a C library error). How about something like `if (! CreateProcessW(...) ) printf("Error = %ld\n", GetLastError());`

Comment: @pmg CreateProcess does not set errno so perror will not work.

Comment: @SteveFriedl the program still did nothing and returned no error. I then decided to run the Administrator: Command Prompt and it executes the program and gives error 126 in cmd prompt. Cubo78 was right that its a exe that needs admin privilege. Is there a way to give admin rights in the code?

Comment: This doesn't feel right: if you can launch `regedit` "by hand" at the command line, then your program should be able to do the same thing. I wonder if some setting in `STARTUPINFOW` might be involved?  On my Windows 10 machine, regedit launched just fine from a non-admin cmd window.